# Views Refresh Results are Scrambled Syntax

Tags: views

On several beta builds recently that use Views, when I am configuring a new page or block view,  when the results are refreshed manually or automatically I am getting a scramble of code/script/syntax garbage instead of a proper Drupal Views admin page with query results. I have a number of other modules installed and have been unable to determine where there might  be a conflict and process of elimination has been more miss than hit. Returning to the main Views admin page and attempting to configure my primary view fine, and the rest of my beta site runs fine. Has anyone encountered view refresh/results during configuration that are just a scramble of syntax output? What solutions? Any known conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I saw this problem recently on a Drupal 7 setup. The modules involved in my case were jQuery update + Calendar but the behaviour in views was the same. Setting jQuery update back to the default (I want to say it's 1.5, not sure) solved the issue with Views and Calendar for me.

Of course I needed jQuery 1.7 for a different purpose, so I had to change it back once the views were done and ready to be used. Not exactly ideal but it worked well enough. Everything functioned fine besides actually making changes to the views.

If you are using jQuery update give changing the jQuery version back a try.

Comment: Thank you Avey! I was thinking that jQuery Update(d) might be the issue after seeing an article that mentioned the $ symbol of jQuery and Drupal might interfere with each other. Yes I had Date and Calender in the mix. I didn't mention that in my question since I didn't want to influence answers.